# Selecting consecutive pairs of data

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a database of tree inventory measurements with a schema as follows:

```
sqlite> .schema mmt
CREATE TABLE mmt (mmtid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, plot TEXT, mmtDate TEXT, treeno NUMERIC, fork TEXT, diameter NUMERIC, height NUMERIC, cwn NUMERIC, form NUMERIC, thin TEXT, comments TEXT, row NUMERIC, heightflag TEXT);
;
```

Tree attributes (diameter and height) are measured every few years. Below is a snippet of data corresponding to tree 1 in plot abc101. This tree has been measured in 2000, 2001, 2003, 2006 and 2009. The fork field indicates that multiple measures have been made on one tree but that does not apply to the data that follows:

```
sqlite> select * from mmt where plot = "abc101" and treeno = 1 ;
mmtid|plot|mmtDate|treeno|fork|diameter|height|cwn|form|thin|comments|row|heightflag
45488|abc101|2000-06-23 00:00:00|1|NULL|14.7||2|2|||1|
45497|abc101|2001-07-20 00:00:00|1|NULL|15.6||2|2|||1|
53683|abc101|2003-09-03 00:00:00|1|NULL|17.3||1|2|||1|
62435|abc101|2006-08-22 00:00:00|1|NULL|20.4|19.25|1|1|||1|H
71314|abc101|2009-01-14 00:00:00|1|NULL|24.1|20.4|1|1|||1|H
```

I would like to structure the data so that I can view consecutive pairs of measurements, something like:

```
plot|mmt1date|treeno|fork|dbh1|mmt2date|dbh2
abc101|2000-06-23 00:00:00|1|NULL|14.7|2001-07-20 00:00:00|15.6
abc101|2001-07-20 00:00:00|1|NULL|15.6|2003-09-03 00:00:00|17.3
```

etc

I am sure that this is a fairly trivial problem. Unfortunately my sql isn't what it could be and I have not found a working solution at this stage. Please can anyone advise on a suitable approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a self-join. Unfortunately, sqlite doesn't support some clever methods involving windowing functions.

```
SELECT *
FROM mmt m1 JOIN mmt m2
ON m1.plot = m2.plot /* whatever else identifies the tree */
AND m2.mmtDate = 
  (SELECT MIN(mmtDate) FROM mmt m3 
   WHERE m3.plot = m1.plot AND m3.mmtDate > m1.mmtDate);
```

Note, you may get better performance using `ORDER BY m3.mmtDate LIMIT 1` in the subquery.

If this is a large table, I would suggest making a special lookup table for years that had entries, keyed in ascending order with an increment of 1.

```
sequence_number   year
1                 2000
2                 2001
3                 2003 /* etc */
```

etc.

and then try

```
SELECT *
FROM mmt m1 JOIN mmt m2
ON m1.plot = m2.plot /* whatever else identifies the tree */
  JOIN year_list y1 ON year(m1.mmtDate)=y1.year
  JOIN year_list y2 ON year(m2.mmtDate)=y2.year
    AND y1.sequence_number = y2.sequence_number-1;
```